# Can't lookup all friends of xxxxxxxxx. Can only lookup for the logged in user (xxxxxxxxx)

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have a facebook application from where I get the friends list of the connected user's friends.

It works because i get only the friends list of my friends who have authorized my application

Here are the queries :

"app_friends":"SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1"

"potential_people":"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 IN (SELECT uid FROM #app_friends)"

It worked fine until today, when I have realized that some of my friends don't authorize me to see their friends. When i m going to see their profile page, i can't see his friends.

So i get the following FQL error : Can't lookup all friends of xxxxxxxxx. Can only lookup for the logged in user (xxxxxxxxx), or friends of the logged in user with the appropriate permission

How can I specify that I want to see the list of the friends of my friends who have authorized my application AND AUTHORIZE ME TO SEE THEIR FRIENDS.

For example I have thougth about something like this :

"app_friends":"SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1 AND **can_access_friends = 1**"

What do you think ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You need to catch this error yourself.

Comment: Close to impossible, Facebook gives users permission controls for a reason, so they can decide - and if they've decided not to let you see, I'm pretty sure theres no way to override that.